# C# Cannot Link nodes in a LinkedList

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, linked-list

I am extending the C# double linked list as a means of creating a custom data structure for a rule engine algorithm I am working on. Unfortunately, the elements in the linked list after instantiation are never actually linked:

```
public abstract class DependencyTree<TTreeLeaf,TTreeLeafNode>
                    : LinkedList<LinkedListNode<TTreeLeaf>>
                    where TTreeLeaf : DependencyTreeLeaf
                    where TTreeLeafNode : DependencyTreeLeafNode
{
    #region Constructors
    public DependencyTree(ICollection<TTreeLeaf> leaves)
    {
        foreach (var leaf in leaves)
        {
            AddLast(new LinkedListNode<TTreeLeaf>(leaf));
        }
        var y = this.Where(node => node.Next != null || node.Previous != null).Count();
        Console.WriteLine(y.ToString());
    }
    #endregion Constructors
```

The above always returns 0, no matter how many Leaves I pass in.

What is the correct way to insure that my leaves are actually linked? I'd rather not roll yet another custom data structure when .NET already has it available.  Any tips are much appreciated.

*****EDIT*****

```
//Addition of DependencyLeaf definition
    public abstract class DependencyTreeLeaf 
        : LinkedList<LinkedListNode<DependencyTreeLeafNode>>
    {
        #region Constructors
        public DependencyTreeLeaf(IEnumerable<DependencyTreeLeafNode> leafNodes, DependencyState siblingDependency = DependencyState.Unset, IEnumerable<DependencyTreeLeaf> children = null, DependencyState childDependency = DependencyState.Unset)
        {
            foreach (var leaf in leafNodes)
            {
                    AddLast(new LinkedListNode<DependencyTreeLeafNode>(leaf));
            }

            if (children != null)
            {
                Children = new LinkedList<LinkedListNode<DependencyTreeLeaf>>();
                foreach (var childLeaf in children)
                {
                    Children.AddLast(new LinkedListNode<DependencyTreeLeaf>(childLeaf));
                }
            }

            SiblingForwardDependency = siblingDependency;
            ChildDownwardDependency = childDependency;
            }
     }
```

Comment: How are you using this abstract class in your code?

Comment: What does the `AddLast` method look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are adding your own linkedlist nodes, you don't need to do this, the linked list will do this. You are adding those `LinkedListNode`s into the actual `LinkedListNode`s, hence, your ones don't have any previous or next being maintained.  However, the problem you are facing is the IEnumerable will iterate over `TTreeLeaf` and not nodes.

If you want to iterate over the Nodes themselves then you need something like :-

```
 public class DependencyTree<TTreeLeaf, TTreeLeafNode>
        : LinkedList<TTreeLeaf>
        where TTreeLeaf : DependencyTreeLeaf
        where TTreeLeafNode : DependencyTreeLeafNode
    {

        public DependencyTree(ICollection<TTreeLeaf> leaves)
        {
            foreach (var leaf in leaves)
            {
                AddLast(leaf);
            }                 

            var y = this.Nodes().Count(node => node.Next != null || node.Previous != null);
            Console.WriteLine(y.ToString());
        }

        public IEnumerable<LinkedListNode<TTreeLeaf>> Nodes()
        {
            var node = this.First;
            while (node != null)
            {
                yield return node;
                node = node.Next;
            }
        }
    }
```

you can of course just go `this.Count();`

Comment: Thanks alot! The error was elementary but no one in my shop was able to catch the simple embedded type I was unwittingly sneaking into the LinkedList declaration. Cheers!